# Unable to set style when parent div container height is changing

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a button that has its position based on container height. Previously the height of the container was fixed and then the button was placed at 1/2 of the container's height. Now I have a container height that is being changed constantly.

```
div.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    > i.fa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;
    }
  }
```

We are using d3 library. How can I set the style top when the height is changing. Can anybody help with this one please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the style function inside the function that is changing the container's height

```
selection.style(name[, value[, priority]])
```

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_style

Comment: $('div.button > i.fa').css('top', 70);